# Files missing after data transfer between SD card connected as a USB OTG pen drive sending to an external SD card on a Samsung Galaxy A42

Tags: samsung, external-sd, file-transfer, usb-on-the-go

I just tried to move about 2 GB of files from an SD card --connected as a USB OTG Pen drive in the USB-C port-- to the "external/removable" SD card mounted inside of the phone.
(*first, I renamed 2 folders and created a third on the receiving SD card inside the phone, which is where the files were to go). After the attempted move, the files appeared to transfer, but then began to disappear. I cannot find these 2GB of files anywhere.

I think I've checked all hidden folders and used data recovery as best I know how on the "receiving" SD card, and I don't think I will find the missing data there. I have done nothing at all to retrieve the data from the "sending" SD card, which indicates that the data was moved due to its total storage capacity decreasing by an amount equal to the transfers, but must still be there if not overwritten.
I then tried to copy about 1GB of files in the same manner, and the files in about 3 folders did transfer, but then only one of the folders was visible for about 30 minutes, and then the folder was empty, and then the original two folders I renamed and the one I created reverted to their conditions prior to my doing anything at all.

I have many memories there, along with years of legal work and other studies, so I must retrieve these files. I also have to move hundreds of other GB worth of data to a single location where I can make backups and such. So:

- Question 1: what am I doing wrong,
- Question 2: where are my files, and
- Question 3: how do I transfer data in the future to avoid this, and which maintains all metadata such as file names and dates taken, between Android storage medium as well as to and from Android to my Windows machines?

Comment: You talked about multiple files. We're file(s) included where knew file has a size if more than 2 GB? Have you used the USB Stick before, so are you sure it works without problems and can hold data up to the specified flash drive size?